# How can I add views next to each other in a scroll view in IOS?

Tags: ios, android-linearlayout

I want to add views in a Scrollview in a for loop. How can I add these views so that each item places next to each other like Linear Layout (Horizontal) in Android?

Comment: I would recommend to use UICollectionView instead.

Answer (score 0):

From iOS 9+ you can use UIStackView to achieve this linear layout.